# Unity Help API Reference missing in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

I've been working with **Visual Studio *2017*** for Unity. When I tried using the shortcut for online documentation (you select a word, press the shortcut and the online documentation about the selected word comes up), it didn't seem to be working.

There's no Help.UnityAPIReference command as well when I looked it up in the Debug -> Options -> Environment ->  Keyboard.

[image]

I've linked VS17 through external tools option in Unity.

What should I do? Should I reinstall VS17? If so, how to? Because it seems to be tightly integrated with Unity and if I uninstall, would it mess up Unity settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue as shown in the question and I just made it work!

**Note: This doesn't fix the missing command in the setting, but you can still use the default shortcut for API reference.**

*If you find those commands on the picture, it means you do install VSTU. The thing you may miss is let VS recognize this is unity project.*

The key is .sln file under your project folder. Make sure you have a correct .sln file. I am new to VS so I just guess the title of project is important(maybe something else).

**To check you make it right:**

You can see when VS recognize Unity project is you can use Unity Project Explorer (and other VSTU tools) list in here. By default, they are disable with non-unity project. So if you see Unity Project Explorer under View menu, the .sln is good to go.

Then, with the correct .sln file, you can open VS either via Unity or loading the .sln on VS. VS will know it is Unity project and enable VSTU.

BTW, I cannot help if you are asking to change the default hotkey for showing reference.(

Comment: How do you identify that it is the "correct .sln file"?

Comment: @Taegost One thing you can see when VS recognize Unity project is you can use Unity Project Explorer (and other VSTU tools) list in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn940020.aspx). By default, they are disable with non-unity project. So if you see Unity Project Explorer under View menu, the .sln is good to go.

Comment: You should include that information in your answer, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the integration via the the VS2017 installer without totally re-installing the program. Just run the installer, uncheck the unity integration if it is checked, let it remove it, then run the installer again with the box checked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've just started using Visual Studio (VS) in Unity, following the Roll a Ball tutorial.  Lesson 2 suggests that Ctrl + ' searches the online Unity documentation for whichever item of code is highlighted at the time.  It didn't.

NB A yellow flag above the VS menu bar suggested I update the software.  I did that.  My new installation of VS (15.6.4) DID include the Help.UnityAPIReference command, which is reported as missing in the original query, and thus NOT showing in the topmost image above.

Yet, the screenshot above indeed shows how to check for it.  The dialogue box shown here is in the 'Tools' menu, under 'Options' .  NB: In case it's not obvious, you need to type 'unity' in the search bar beneath 'Show commands containing:'

The default shortcut to access the Help was set as 'Ctrl + Alt + M, Ctrl + H (Global)', suggesting to me that on hitting of these, I would be whisked away to the online Unity API Help documentation shown in the tutorial.  That wasn't happening.

So I did the following:
1. with Help.UnityAPIReference selected, ..
2. I clicked under 'Use new shortcut in:' and ..
3. selected 'CSharp Editor' from the list
4. Then, with the cursor in the 'Press shortcut keys:' box,...
5. I held down Ctrl and pressed '.
6. Nothing (ie no conflict) appeared in the box below marked 'Shortcut currently used by:', so ..
7. I hit the 'Assign' button.
And Hey Presto! I can select a command in VS, hit Ctrl +' and it goes straight to the relevant section in the online documentation.

NB I had previously also gone into the 'Tools - Options' setting for 'Tools for Unity'.  With the 'General' sub-menu selected on the left, I changed the setting under 'Documentation' for 'Use external browser' from 'false' to 'true'.  Thus, Ctrl + ' opens my browser. Else, the help file appears within VS.  My set-up makes the relevant info accessible much quicker by opening the browser rather than asking VS to load it as another tab.  Also VS seems to respond to each subsequent request for Help by replacing the previous search if this is done within VS, whereas, when it is all set to 'Use external browser', it generates a new browser tab for each new search. Smart!

Answer (score 1):

Building on Edens answer, I renamed the `*.sln` solution file in my project. On restarting Unity and then starting VS by opening a script, the `*.sln` was regenerated and I could see the VSTU tools as well as access the docs with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.
(Who defines these hotkeys?!)

Comment: you can post a question about that hotkeys.

Comment: Yea... I didn't mean "How do you define hotkeys in Visual Studio?" but "Who designs a hotkey like that?" It's super awkward to type.