# Unity Documentation Access doesn't work from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, unity-game-engine

The standard shortcut is **CTRL+ALT+M,CTRL+H** for Unity Documentation Access doesn't work and command "Help.UnityAPIReference" doesn't exist in the list of

[**Debug > Options and Settings > Environment > Keyboard**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eGOo.png)

or

[**Tool > Options and Settings > Environment > Keyboard**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfjHu.png)

C# script from Visual Studio 2017 to Unity5.6.3p1 working perfectly fine, so what option do I have to fix it?

I appreciate any thoughts about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621355/unity-help-api-reference-missing-in-visual-studio/47539008#47539008) can help you.

You may check step by step:

1. VSTU installed.
2. VS recognize Unity project.
3. Other shortcuts works fine.

If all items in the checklist pass and only the API reference shortcut doesn't work, you can simply make up one yourself.